# How to get mongodb role list from nodejs driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongos running in the backend and want to use nodejs driver to query user role list. The code I am using is:

```
db.db('admin').command({ rolesInfo: 1, showBuiltinRoles: true })
.then((roleList) => {
      console.log('role list', roleList);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

it works fine on a singles mongo instance and replica set. But it always return empty list when connecting to a `mongos`. If I run this command through mongo shell for the same `mongos` server it gives me the correct output:

```
db.runCommand({rolesInfo: 1, showBuiltinRoles:true})
```

the mongos version is 3.4.4 and nodejs driver version is 2.2. I wonder why doesn't driver work in this case.

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps you are connecting with a user lacking the [`viewRole`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#viewRole) action. I start a simple setup with `mongo --nodb; MongoRunner.dataPath = 'my/data/path'; new ShardingTest({ shards: 2, mongos: 1 })` Connect to mongos and issue the command. Viola! roles returned.

Comment: I use the same command in the mongo shell and I can get the correct result. But I can't get it from the nodejs driver. Did you use native nodejs driver or any other driver library?

Comment: Yep. Just ran a quick test with the core driver. No issue. Your mongoose code simply grabs the same underlying object from the core driver connection, so that's not an issue, unless you are grabbing `db` from the wrong place that is.

Comment: I am not using mongoose. And I can use the `db` for other calls. It only doesn't work for querying user roles in mongos. It works fine if I change the connection uri to replicaset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a software issue. You might have a permissions issue in your setup, but that's not really a topic for here and it's easy to produce a simple test case.

As commented earlier, simply do a sharding test environment starting the shell with no database connection:

```
mongo --nodb
```

Then set a directory where the test environment can create data:

```
MongoRunner.dataPath = '/path/to/test/'
```

And start a simple sharded  cluster for testing:

```
new ShardingTest({ shards: 2, mongos: 1 })
```

Check the port where `mongos` is running on. Mine is `20005`. Then you can either simply run the command in the shell, or through a nodejs program as:

```
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:20005/test';

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}

(async function() {

  let db;

  try {

    db = await MongoClient.connect(uri);

    let admin = db.admin();

    let result = await admin.command({ rolesInfo: 1, showBuiltinRoles: 1 });

    log(result);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }

})()
```

Or if you really must use mongoose, but it's only just getting the object from the underlying driver anyway:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:20005/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    let admin = conn.db.admin();

    let result = await admin.command({ rolesInfo: 1, showBuiltinRoles: 1 });

    log(result);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})()
```

Any way you do it, it returns the list of roles:

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "__system",
      "db": "admin",
      "isBuiltin": true,
      "roles": [],
      "inheritedRoles": []
    },
    {
      "role": "backup",
      "db": "admin",
      "isBuiltin": true,
      "roles": [],
      "inheritedRoles": []
    },
    {
      "role": "clusterAdmin",
      "db": "admin",
      "isBuiltin": true,
      "roles": [],
      "inheritedRoles": []
    },
    ...
```

As stated, you might have a permissions issue or other configuration issue in the cluster. You should make sure the user has [`viewRole`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#viewRole), but really "roles access" is a database administration topic you can ask on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) instead.

The software works just as designed and just as the test case here proves.

Comment: You are right, it is probably my server issue. I tried in a clean environment and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: what I don't understand is why mongo shell gives me different permission than nodejs driver. I am able to list roles through mongo shell but can't get anything through driver. I use the same user for both cases.

Comment: @ZhaoYi I don't know what "your code" is doing. All I can do is provide a clear an reproducible case that gets the expected results. The point of this is your code needs to be doing the same thing. Anything else as mentioned, is a configuration issue. I know from previous posts you are working on a tool, so the best way to start testing is from the :"ground up". Just as I have done in example for you here.